# UITabBarIcon Images Display Properly in XIB But Not When Running

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a UITabBar with three icons. I put the images in the Images.xcassets folder:

[image: Images.xcassets folder]

I then add those to the icons:

[image]

And all three show up properly when viewing the XIB:

[image]

However when running all the pictures are tiny:

[image]

How do I fix this?

**EDIT:**

After putting the images into the 1x category in the Images.xcassets folder the XIB still has sharp pictures but when running the pictures become blurry:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have images for retina display? 
You should have clock.png and clock@2x.png images. @2x images should be 2 times bigger then ordinary images. 
So, I assume that images are small because you're missing images for retina display, or you're images are not named correctly (@2x is missing).

Comment: The icon pack I got them in only had one image. I guess they were not @2x. When I switched them to 1x in the Images.xcassets the images still show up fine in the XIB but when running they become very blurry.

Comment: Yes, many icon packs gives non retina images for free, and you should pay to get images for Retina screen. If you're testing on device with retina display, then your device tries to find, for example, clock@2x.png image. If it doesn't find the image then the device will find clock.png image and he'll scale it up. That's the reason why your images are blurry. To fix this problem, as I said, you should have clock.png (for example 30x30px) and clock@2x.png (60x60px). Then you're images will be sharp and correctly sized.